# How to make my application disappear from Windows Volume Mixer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am building an application in Visual Studio C#, how can I make it not appear in the Volume Mixer?

[image: desc]

Comment: I want to know the opposite: How did you make it appear in the Volume Mixer?

Comment: I thought dropping the AudioRenderClient would cause it to be removed, but it turns out that isn't the case...